# Python - Introduce a list of RGB values in a sorting algorithm?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I need to modify the following algorithm so that it can sort a list of RGB values from an jpg image. I get the values with numpy and PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
def maxList(A): 
    return(max(num for num in A))
def obtainDigit(num, n): 
    return (num // 10 ** n) % 10
def linkLists(A): 
    lAux = [] 
    for sublist in A: 
        lAux.extend(sublist) 
    return(lAux)
def generateSublists(A, digito): 
    subListsAux = [[] for i in range(10)] //This 10 should be 255, since that is the max value for the RGB matrix numbers. 
    for num in A: 
        subListsAux[obtainDigit(num, digit)].append(num) 
    return(subListsAux)
def radixSort(A): 
    interations = len(str(maxList(A))) 
    for digit in range(iterations): 
        sublists = generateSublists(A, digit) 
        A = linkLists(sublists) 
    return(A)

image=Image.open("eliot.jpg")
image=np.array(image)
```

What I need is to use image as an argument for radixSort. But first I need to modify some parts of the algorithm, I just don't know which ones. The algorithm works perfectly for any list of numbers.

Comment: Could you explain your question little further with an example.

Comment: I can't think of an example but this: if you add a list and use it in the algorithm, the list will be sorted from highest to lowest. 
    a=[34, 52, 12, 86, 90, 3, 44] 
    print(radixSort(a))
Output:
    [3,12,34,44,52,86,90]
With the tuples generated by image it should be something like this:
(100,100,100),(255,0,0),(200,200,200),(0,255,0)
Output:
(0,255,0),(100,100,100),(200,200,200),(255,0,0)